# System.Data.DataView.Find method: substring starts-with not possible?

Tags: .net, find, substring, dataview, system.data

Is it possible to use the Find() method of the DataView object to return the index of a row where the column used in the default sort *starts with* a particular string?

I've been trying various permutations and the only one that seems to work is an exact string match for the column-value.

I am not trying to filter-out non-matching records -- just trying to move to the first matching one.

Thanks